# Error: ur5_ros-gazebo package not found

Tags: ros-kinetic, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I cloned a package into my catkin_ws/src folder with 'git clone [https://github.com/lihuang3/ur5_ROS-Gazebo.git'](https://github.com/lihuang3/ur5_ROS-Gazebo.git%27), then catkin_make & source devel/setup.bash (all works fine)

```
laurah@laurah-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/laurah/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/laurah/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/laurah/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/laurah/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/laurah/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/laurah/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/laurah/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target _ur_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_IOStates
...
[100%] Built target ur_driver
[100%] Built target ur_msgs_generate_messages
[100%] Built target ur5_notebook_generate_messages
laurah@laurah-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
laurah@laurah-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/catkin_ws$ ls -a src
.  ..  CMakeLists.txt  universal_robot  ur5_ROS-Gazebo  ur_modern_driver
laurah@laurah-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/catkin_ws$ rospack find ur5_ROS-Gazebo
[rospack] Error: package 'ur5_ROS-Gazebo' not found
laurah@laurah-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun ur5_ROS-Gazebo testmotion.py
[rospack] Error: package 'ur5_ROS-Gazebo' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?
I am using Ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322538/error:-ur5_ros-gazebo-package-not-found/) by [lr_k123](https://answers.ros.org/users/41103/lr_k123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-06**:
Did you remember to build the workspace? You can't just clone a package and try execute scripts/binaries in it.

**Comment by [lr_k123](https://answers.ros.org/users/41103/lr_k123/) on 2019-05-06**:
Oh I thought catkin_make would be enough. I will try catkin build first thing tomorrow. Thank you for the fast reply :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-06**:
`catkin_make` is enough. That is what "building your workspace" means.

Did you also `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`?

**Comment by [Tyrel](https://answers.ros.org/users/40650/tyrel/) on 2019-05-06**:
The only error I see when I look at the package on github is that the python file is named `testmotion.py` instead of `tesmotion.py`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-07**:
That would become a problem if/when `roslaunch` is able to find the package. That isn't happening according to what @lr_k123 tells us, so that's something to fix first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The cause of the error is that the package is actually called `ur5_notebook` instead of `ur5_ROS-Gazebo` (see [here](https://github.com/lihuang3/ur5_ROS-Gazebo/blob/2f7b9b056bb41b9412f86589a60e25ba2816b78b/package.xml#L3) in the manifest). The latter is only the name of the repository (and the directory in your workspace).

The following should work:

```
rosrun ur5_notebook testmotion.py
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lr_k123](https://answers.ros.org/users/41103/lr_k123/) on 2019-05-07**:
Thank you very much! I did not see that. Do you also advise to rename `~/catkin_ws/src/ur5_ROS-Gazebo` to `~/catkin_ws/src/ur5_notebook` or will that cause other problems?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-07**:
re: rename: it's not really necessary, but if you'd like to it won't harm anything. You'll probably have to rebuild your workspace though.